# How create a size_t and how count the size?

Tags: objective-c, c, size-t

I create a NSData and use the function

```
- (const void *)bytes;
```

So, it return the bytes in a `const void *` variable. If I read the memory manually I will find this:

```
98 F3 00 76 84    //Then a lot of zero
```

Use `strlen` not work because the `00`. But it will be aways the same size: 10 hexa lenght. So, to create a manually size_t, I will use:

```
size_t mysize = 0x0A
```

Or I have use the size in bits:

```
size_t mysize = 0x28
```

Is any of this correct?

Comment: Have you checked `-(NSUInteger)length` of NSData?

Comment: No.. Lol, I didn't have this idea.. Very more easy and error-free...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSData` contains the length.

```
const void *mybytes = [data bytes];
size_t mysize = [data length];
```

Comment: Wow, I forget this... lenght is not in NSData.h (I already search).. Is in other object... putz...

Comment: Did you search for length, or lenght <- the spelling is incorrect?

Comment: This was stupid.. One line above the function bytes, is the function length.. My error..

Answer (score 2):

NSData also has `-(NSUInteger)length`.